# REST sort descending with minus ('-') symbol, rather than <propertyName>.dir=desc

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, sorting, spring-data

I'm trying out Spring Data with MongoDB and REST as [shown here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/).  One thing I noticed is that to sort results, you add a query parameter named .dir with a value of "asc" or "desc".

In many REST APIs I've used, the mechanism for sorting was to simply put a minus ("-") symbol in front of the property name in the sort (or order) parameter.

Is there any way I could customize Spring to allow for this behavior?

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm referring to, from http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#advanced-queries.  
  
`GET /tickets?sort=-priority,created_at`

Comment: Yes, you are probably going to have to override the standard `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that your app is using: eg. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java

Comment: Looks promising.  Do you know how I would configure Spring to use my customized SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver?

Answer (score 0):

I remembered I stumbled on this thread before I made the customized resolver. You can use `SimpleSortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` class on https://github.com/sancho21/spring-data-commons/commit/6c90a9cfcb50b2ed0e7a25db0cfd64d36e7065da

Please comment to support its adoption on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/pull/166/files

As for reminder, in order to use this class, you need to inject an instance of it into the existing the constructor of existing `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` instance.